# How do I use a template from one app in another app

Tags: django, django-templates

Currently trying to make a social application. I created two apps Main and posts. My post app will handle all functionality for creating, deleting a post, list of posts. My Main app is my homepage which would display all posts, for example similar to a Facebook's homepage.

Main app currently authenticates users and what not. I created views and template for my posts app and I now want to include it on the Main's app homepage. Not sure how to go out about doing this. Not asking for anyone to write up the code but at least give a structure on how to achieve this.

Basic Structure of the app:

```
--Main_app
  --_views.py
  --templates
    --home.html
--posts_app
  --_views.py
  --templates
    --posts.html
```

---

One of the files my posts_app views contains currently is:

```py
def posts_list(request):
    # return HttpResponse("<h1> List a posts. </h1>")
    render(requests, "posts.html", {})
```

---

templates/posts.html contains this file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <h1>Posts template is working</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

And in my main_app templates/HTML:

```html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h1>Homepage</h1>
  <!-- Posts template -->
  {% include "posts/templates/posts.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

---

It made sense to me at the time to just import the template from the posts app to the main app and it would work. Did not work obviously, so I did a bit of research and couldn't find a definite solution, is there thing called templates inheritance, should import my views from posts into main. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to add a template in the project directory not in app, if you want to use that same template.

```
-myproject\
          -Main_app\
          -posts_app\
          -templates\
                     -template_name.html
```

And in settings add,

```
    TEMPLATES = [
       {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],# Add this line
        'APP_DIRS': True, 
         ........
```

In your views you can refer that directly like `template_name.html`

Other way is to create template in the directory like

```
myproject\
         -Main_app\
                   -templates\
                             -Main_app\
                                        mytemplate.html
         -posts_app\
```

Now you can use that by referring `Main_app\mytemplate.html`

The first one is very efficient in this case.

Comment: Ok in regards to the first way, I would put my main.html and my posts.html in the templates folder in the root directory. Then I would import my posts.html into the main.html, correct? Also would I still render the posts.html inside of the posts.views?

Comment: Do I include*  {% include "posts/posts.html" %} --> inside of the shared.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is place your templates folder on the root of your project directory. So instead of having

```
--Main_app
  --_views.py
  --templates
    --home.html
--posts_app
  --_views.py
  --templates
    --posts.html
```

You can do

```
--Main_app
  --_views.py

--posts_app
  --_views.py
--templates
  --SHARED.html
  --main
    --home.html
  --posts
    --posts.html
```

And in your views you could do something like:

```
return render(request, 'SHARED.html', context)  # For shared

return render(request, 'posts/posts.html', context)  # For template in posts
```

Comment: Do I have to do {% include "posts/posts.html" %} --> inside of the shared.html?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to create a separate `templates` directory in your root project folder. This way you can access html files in any app you wish. Your directory structure would look something like this:

```
.
├── blog
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-35.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── blog_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-35.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-35.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── base.css
└── templates
    ├── base.html
    ├── home.html
    ├── post_detail.html
    └── post_new.html
```

[This is a simple blog I made using Django](https://github.com/C-Anirudh/Blog-Hub)

It might be of some help if you want a reference.

Comment: Ok makes sense, but how do I get the post_new.html to show up in the base.html or home.html? Do I just have to use {% include "posts_new.html" %}  inside the base.html or home.html?

Comment: @alongtest12 you can `extend` templates, not include them. That said, you might include `post_new.html` in `home.html` if your logic is such. You can google about extending templates or view the html files in the project link I shared.

Answer (score 0):

As for cross loading templates via different apps, I would recommend structuring your project so that `templates` is a separate directory, this will benefit you in two ways:

1. It will be easier to totally separate front-end from back-end later on.
2. It will add modularity since it will decrease coupling between your apps.

Example Templates Director:

```
── templates
│   ├── main
│   ├── another_cool_app
│   ├── accounts
│   ├── posts
│   │   ├── timeline.html
│   │   ├── post_details.html
```

And so on.

For loading templates inside other templates you can simply:

```
{% include "posts/timeline.html" with posts_list=user.friends_posts %}
```

Happy coding.